# Freetds php package is outdated for macOS Catalina?

Tags: php, macos, sha256, freetds, php-8.2

The error stops when installing the freetds package and is present with SHA256 verification.

```
Downloading https://www.freetds.org/files/stable/freetds-1.4.tar.bz2
######################################################################### 100.0%
Error: freetds: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: 1dd62979822d46ca67635bf7114f84255016b49bd9e262f254067455238dbb70
  Actual: 35cb55743c5c2e0b579caf180eebb5cb4a65155b7c7aa3428c1b6b5d3cc291f4
    File: /Users/efra/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/36ff084509e535911d49682dbeaa6a46892a6c4a6d5ebecfb163a767213c3078--freetds-1.4.tar.bz2
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

The error stops when installing the freetds package and is present with SHA256 verification.

I have tried deleting the file as specified with rm and then ran brea cleanup and brew update, also brew upgrade.

The error persists.

I would like to install PHP correctly in its most stable version, I already have curl and the latest version of brew installed.